# Impressions or tracking on Flutter widget

Tags: flutter, impressions

I want to track if a widget is show on the screen. Like a card in a list view.
There is a widget in Flutter like GestureDetector for impression or tracking?

Comment: I didn't get you, can you explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into the [firebase_analytics](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_analytics) plugin. You can set it up to track when users look at certain pages. See the plugin page for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library for this https://github.com/623637646/flutter_impression

```dart
ImpressionDetector(
  impressedCallback: () {
    debugPrint('impressed');
  },
  child: MyWidget(),
)
```